# Integral of $-(\frac{z^{-2}}{1 - z^{-1}})$ between $0$ and $z$ (relates to Z transform)

Tags: integration, limits, z-transform

This example comes from the Z-transform chapter of "Signals and Linear Systems" (3rd edition) by Gabel & Roberts. I can't quite replicate their result. The book states

$$-\int_0^z \frac{z^{-2}}{1-{z^{-1}}}\;\mathrm{d\hat{z}}=-\ln(1-z^{-1})$$
I believe this may be re-written as
$$-\int_0^z \frac{1}{z-{z^2}}\;\mathrm{d\hat{z}}$$

Note that we have the condition $1<|z|$

Using hints from Wolfram (without Go Pro), I then re-phrased the problem as
$$-\int_0^z \frac{1}{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2-\left(z-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}\;\mathrm{d\hat{z}}$$

(The above should be better formatted, not sure how to get the correct relative 'heights' yet)

Then using a table of integrals, e.g. here (https://math24.net/integration-completing-square.html)
$$-\int \frac{1}{a^2-z^2}\;\mathrm{dx}=\frac{1}{2a}\ln\left|\frac{a+x}{a-x}\right|$$
and writing $u=z-\frac{1}{2},du=d\hat{z},a=\frac{1}{2}$
$$-\int_0^z \frac{d\hat{z}}{(\frac{1}{2})^2-u^2}\;=\ln\left| \frac{\frac{1}{2}+(z-\frac{1}{2})}{\frac{1}{2}-\left(z-\frac{1}{2}\right)} \right|$$
$$=\ln\left|\frac{1}{z}-1\right|$$ as the indefinite integral

This has the opposite sign to the book's stated result, and I do not know if this is because the book is showing the results once the limits are substituted.

However, I am unclear about using the given limits. Is the lower limit that shown for the integral i.e. 0, or maybe "just a little bit over 1" due to the convergence range given for z?

---

Thanks for the title edit, and the comments. Strictly, the book uses
$$\int_0^zf(z)d\hat{z}$$ with the comment "*We note that $\hat{z}$ in this expression may be treated as if it were a real variable*".

I've now changed the integrals to refect this. Maybe one error I made was to assume that I could write "$dz$" in place of "$d\hat{z}$" in light of that remark.

Comment: Please also use MathJax in the title.

Comment: Never write $\int_0^zf(z)dz$. You mean $\int_0^zf(w)dw$.

Comment: $$\frac{z^{-2}}{1 - z^{-1}} = \frac1{z^2 - z} \neq \frac1{z-z^2}$$